# Problem using map with a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, exponentiation

I am using Haskell to solve problem 99 in euler project, where I must find the maximum result from a list of base exponent pairs.

I came up with this:

```
prob99 = maximum $ map ((fst)^(snd)) numbers
```

Where the numbers are in the form:

```
numbers = [[519432,525806],[632382,518061],[78864,613712]..
```

Why doesn't this work? Do I need to change the format of the numbers?
Is there a simple optimisation here I am not thinking of, like a more efficient method of exponentiation?

Comment: @Jonno_FTW: regarding the hoogle discussion, I suggest to have a look at hlint too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because fst and snd are defined on pairs (types fst :: (a,b) -> a and snd :: (a,b) -> b). And second problem is with (fst)^(snd), you cannot power function on function.

```
prob99 = maximum $ map (\xs -> (head xs)^(head (tail xs))) numbers
```

or

```
prob99 = maximum $ map (\xs -> (xs !! 0)^(xs !! 1)) numbers
```

Comment: you could also pattern match out the first and second elements, i.e. maximum $ map (\(a : b : _) -> a^b) numbers

Answer (score 12):

> Give a man a fish, and you'll feed him for a day, teach a man to fish, and you'll feed him for a lifetime.

Jonno, you should learn how to let GHC's error messages help you, and the "`undefined` drop in" method (let's focus on that for now).

```
ghci> let numbers = [[519432,525806],[632382,518061]]
ghci> -- so far so good..
ghci> let prob99 = maximum $ map ((fst)^(snd)) numbers

<Bam! Some type error>

ghci> -- ok, what could have gone wrong?
ghci> -- I am pretty sure that this part is fine:
ghci> let prob99 = maximum $ map undefined numbers
ghci> -- yes, it is fine
ghci> -- so the culprit must be in the "((fst)^(snd))" part
ghci> let f = ((fst)^(snd))

<Bam! Some type error>

ghci> -- whoa, so this function never makes sense, not just where I used it..
ghci> -- is it doing what I think it is doing? lets get rid of those braces
ghci> let f = fst ^ snd

<Bam! Same type error>

ghci> -- yeah I got my syntax right alright
ghci> -- well, can I exponent fst?
ghci> let f = fst ^ undefined

No instance for (Num ((a, b) -> a))
  arising from a use of '^' at <interactive>:1:8-22
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num ((a, b) -> a))
In the expression: fst ^ undefined
In the definition of 'f': f = fst ^ undefined

ghci> -- duh, fst is not a Num
ghci> -- this is what I wanted:
ghci> let f x = fst x ^ snd x
ghci> -- now lets try it
ghci> let prob99 = maximum $ map f numbers

<Bam! Some type error>

ghci> -- still does not work
ghci> -- but at least f makes some sense now
ghci> :t f

f :: (Num a, Integral b) => (a, b) -> a

ghci> -- lets find an example input for it
ghci> head numbers

[519432,525806]

ghci> :t head numbers

head numbers :: [Integer]

ghci> -- oh, so it is a list of two integers and not a tuple!
ghci> let f [a, b] = a ^ b
ghci> let prob99 = maximum $ map f numbers
ghci> -- no error?
ghci> -- finally I got the types right!
```

Answer (score 5):

What's not working is your program's type consistency.  You're trying to apply function `(^)`, simplified type `Int -> Int -> Int`, to arguments of type `(a,a) -> a` (not an Int).

The easiest way would probably be to directly generate a list of pairs instead of a list of lists.  You can then (almost) directly appply the (^) function to them, uncurrying it first.

```
numbers = [(519432,525806),(632382,518061),(78864,613712)...
prob99 = maximum $ map (uncurry (^)) numbers
```

If you're stuck with your sublists, you could pattern-match them directly, improving a bit on Matajon's solution:

```
prob99 = maximum $ map (\[x,y] -> x^y) numbers
```

Or, if you're into point-free style all the way, you can make good use of the operators in `Control.Arrow`.  (which in this case doesn't help much as far as verbosity goes)

```
prob99 = maximum $ map ((!!0) &&& (!!1) >>> uncurry (^)) numbers
```

Comment: how can I find at what position in the main list the maximum numbers appears?

Comment: That's an entirely different question!  One obvious way is to find the maximum value first, then look for its index, but that wastes most of the benefits of generating the list lazily.  There are better ways, but they need more context about what you're trying to do (and more space than a comment.)

Comment: 'uncurry' is in the Prelude, there's no need to import it from 'Data.Function'.